# How do I register client dynamically in Spring Authorization Server 1.0.0?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I would like to register client dynamically in Spring Authorization Server 1.0.0. Anyone please help me by providing a guideline. I couldn't find anything in google search or Spring Authorization Server docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RegisteredClientRepository` interface provides a `save` method that you can use to save new clients to your implementation. You only need to inject the `RegisteredClientRepository` bean in your class and call the method passing the required value.